# Will Ubuntu minimal cd install ubuntu-desktop on release upgrade or just installed packages?

Tags: upgrade

Normal ubuntu desktop will update ubuntu-desktop package and it's dependencies on release upgrade. Will Ubuntu minimal cd install ubuntu-desktop on release upgrade or just installed packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal CD is not intended for release upgrading, it's intended for installing the base system + whatever packages you need, including ubuntu-desktop. If the installation is upgraded, it affects the installed packages, regardless of whether the installation is a server or a desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can now choose my preferred desktop environment on my ubuntu minimal and upgrade my preferred packages only on upgrade. Thanks